# Como atualizar a pagina de um site após ter mudado o valor de um campo por VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, excel-vba

Boa noite.

Gostaria de saber como posso atualizar a pagina com a data que eu informei por VBA. Eu coloco a data mas a página não muda. Como não tem um botão, não sei o que fazer.

```
Sub Links()

    Dim ie              As Object
    Dim tabela          As Object
    Dim Liga, DataHora  As String
    Dim Home, Away      As String
    Dim Link, data      As String
    Dim ResultadoFinal  As String
    Dim Posiz1, Posiz2  As Long
    Dim linha

    data = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Plan1").Range("AD2")

    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    ie.Visible = True

    URL = "https://betsapi.com/cs/basketball/"
    ie.Navigate URL

    State = 0
    Do Until State = 4
        DoEvents
        State = ie.ReadyState
    Loop

    'até consigo mudar a data, mas ao mudar a data a pagina deveria se ajustar a essa data 
    '(como ocorre ao clicar de forma manual), mas isso não ocorre ao preencher pelo vba.
    ie.Document.forms.Item(1).Item(0).Value = Sheets("Plan1").Range("AD2") 'conte uma data. Ex: 2018-05-06

    Text1 = ie.Document.Body.innerHTML

    Text1 = Replace(Text1, "a href=/r/", "CJOS QUER ")


    'Coleta a parte importante dos links com base no meu marcador
    Posiz1 = 1
    i = 1
        Do
            On Error GoTo sai

            Posiz1 = InStr(Posiz1, Text1, "CJOS QUER ")

            Posiz1 = InStr(Posiz1, Text1, "CJOS QUER ") + 10
            Posiz2 = InStr(Posiz1, Text1, ">")

            Link = Trim(Mid(Text1, Posiz1, Posiz2 - Posiz1))
            c = InStr(1, Link, "/")
            Range("A" & i) = Left(Link, c - 1)
            Range("H" & i) = "https://betsapi.com/rs/bet365/" & Link
            Posiz1 = Posiz2 + 1
            i = i + 1
        Loop
sai:

    ie.Quit
    Set tabela = Nothing
    Set ie = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Declarando a variável `Dim formData As MSHTML.HTMLFormElement`, definindo como `Set formData = ie.document.getElementById("datepicker").form` e enviando o formulário `formData.submit` é possível enviar. Porém não envia a data alterada com o valor `.Value`, mas sim a data de hoje. Usei o FireEvent  "OnChange" e `keybd_event VK_RETURN, 0&, 0&, 0&` sem sucesso. Vamos esperar ver se akguém possui a resposta e perguntarei no SOen para ver se consigo a resposta porque fiquei curioso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olha a solução que encontrei. Não está elegante, mas está funcionando (não sei por quanto tempo)... Se alguém tiver uma ideia melhor, eu aceito.

```
Sub Links()

    Dim ie              As Object
    Dim tabela          As Object
    Dim Liga, DataHora  As String
    Dim Home, Away      As String
    Dim Link, data      As String
    Dim ResultadoFinal  As String
    Dim Posiz1, Posiz2  As Long
    Dim linha

    data = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Plan1").Range("AD2")

    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    ie.Visible = True

    'A data tem uma / no final. Ex: 2018-05-06/
    URL = "https://betsapi.com/cs/basketball/" & data
    ie.Navigate URL

    State = 0
    Do Until State = 4
        DoEvents
        State = ie.ReadyState
    Loop

    ie.Refresh
    Application.Wait TimeSerial(Hour(Now()), Minute(Now()), Second(Now()) + 5)

    Text1 = ie.Document.Body.innerHTML

    Text1 = Replace(Text1, "a href=/r/", "CJOS QUER ")


    'Coleta a parte importante dos links com base no meu marcador
    Posiz1 = 1
    i = 1
        Do
            On Error GoTo sai

            Posiz1 = InStr(Posiz1, Text1, "CJOS QUER ")

            Posiz1 = InStr(Posiz1, Text1, "CJOS QUER ") + 10
            Posiz2 = InStr(Posiz1, Text1, ">")

            Link = Trim(Mid(Text1, Posiz1, Posiz2 - Posiz1))
            c = InStr(1, Link, "/")
            Range("A" & i) = Left(Link, c - 1)
            Range("H" & i) = "https://betsapi.com/rs/bet365/" & Link
            Posiz1 = Posiz2 + 1
            i = i + 1
        Loop

    sai:
    ie.Quit
    Set tabela = Nothing
    Set ie = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Nossa, verdade. Nem percebi que mudando o href isso podia ser realizado.

Comment: Pior que eu já tinha tentado isso, mas ao atualizar a pagina ela ia para o dia de hoje (atualizando de forma manual)... Mas com o ie.Refresh ela atualizou mantendo a data escolhida

Comment: Só um adendo ao seu código... FWIW: A sua declaração está errada, pois com `Dim Liga, DataHora  As String`, Liga está declarada como Variant e DataHora como String. O correto seria  `Dim Liga As String, DataHora  As String`

Comment: Não entendi... eu declarei: Dim Liga, DataHora  As String   Não estaria as duas variáveis como sendo String?

Comment: Não em VBA, Liga está como Variant. Depois da declaração veja `Debug.Print TypeName(Liga)` e `Debug.Print TypeName(DataHora)`. Uma será string e outra Empty que é variant. No começo eu também declarava errado por causa de outra linguagem de programação que aprendi.